# Can't find manifest option

Tags: c#, manifest

I wan't to add manifest file but I don't find this option.

How to find it?

[image]

Comment: 1+ for top pain skills

Comment: Do you know how to add manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add the Manifest File to your solution, you need to add it to a project.

Right click project > add > new item > Application Manifest File

Comment: That's what I did, but there is not such option, "Application manifest file".

Comment: I can see from your screenshot that you are adding an item to your `Solution` You need to be adding a file to your `Project`

Comment: Oh, yes!! now I can see it! It's hard for me to upvote to a person who downvoted for the post...

Comment: Doesn't exist for me.